# how to use liferay's Nested Portlet inside my own portlets?

Tags: liferay

i am developing a portlet for liferay.

i need to include liferay's Nested Portlet in my own portlet.

is it possible?

ps: i am new to liferay. please answer with detail description. ;)

Comment: What do yopu mean by "nested portlet"? Whay exactly are yu rying to do?

Comment: Seems you don't really need an answer since you don't respond.

Comment: nested portlet? What's your requirment

Answer (score 1):

This thing is not possible while you asked for Nested portlet in your Custom portlet.
If you want your Custom-portlet inside "Liferay" Nested-portlet then you can actually use it .

Nested Portlet provide your the functionality to contain all the related portlet inside the one portlet. It is depending upon use-case.

For further information just revert the post.

Answer (score 1):

```
<liferay-portlet:runtime portletName="3"></liferay-portlet:runtime>
```

3 is the portlet id

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, yes it is possible to have [nested portlets in liferay](http://www.liferay.com/web/guest/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Nested%20Portlets%20Portlet) (there's a link at the end of the article, make sure you don't miss it)

Answer (score 0):

Check the source code of the out-of-the-box portlet that nests other portlets.
In Liferay 5.2.3 it uses com.liferay.portlet.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePortletUtil.processPortlet(...) method.

Note: I've been trying to develop separate portlet that would use this API, but got null pointer exceptions inside Liferay logic, so it seems that you'll have to develop your portlet in EXT environment (though this might be different in Liferay 6 for example, I've been using Liferay 5.2.3).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can add nested portlets to your application. [Check this](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/Portal/liferay-portal-4.4.2/com/liferay/portlet/nestedportlets/action/ConfigurationActionImpl.java.htm)

[1](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/Portal/liferay-portal-4.4.2/com/liferay/portlet/nestedportlets/action/ConfigurationActionImpl.java.htm): http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Nested+Portlets+Portlet and [this](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/Portal/liferay-portal-4.4.2/com/liferay/portlet/nestedportlets/action/ConfigurationActionImpl.java.htm) is the ActionImpl file concerned to nestedportlets, in liferay.